# Postfix "Relay access deined" error with Outlook

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, smtp

I am following [this](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/) tutorial and finished the basic setup. I can login and send via squirrel mail and telnet but receive a "relay access denied" error in the logs when i try and send from Outlook. all port are forwarded correctly and are open. what could be wrong?

Thanks, nat

Comment: Show logs from postfix and relevant part of configs

Comment: And read [1-st class docs](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html), at least

Answer (score 0):

SMTP authentication is not working properly. You have not enabled SMTP authentication in you outlook setting. If you have got the SASL authentication config part working properly from  flurdy doc then it is only a problem with your outlook settings. This error happens only when you try to send to a domain other than the one you have used for your mail server. Sending local will work but not to other domains.

Comment: I have enabled SASL, more details and a breakdown of my mail.conf are here: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11737869)

Comment: What I meant is can you check your outlook settings not the server settings. In the outlook outgoing server configuration you have to enable my server requires authentication.

Comment: Out look then returns an error that says "your SMTP server does not recognize this type of authentication." it gave this error before and after SASL.

Comment: In your smtp settings in outlook make sure it us using plain text authentication and SSL is disabled.